# Recuperar elementos pela class no IE8 com JS puro

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Tenho isso :

```
<input type="hidden" value="<c:out value='${destino }' />" class="destino" />
<input type="hidden" value="<c:out value='${destino }' />" class="destino" />
<input type="hidden" value="<c:out value='${destino }' />" class="destino" />
<input type="hidden" value="<c:out value='${destino }' />" class="destino" />
<input type="hidden" value="<c:out value='${destino }' />" class="destino" />
```

e estou tentando recuperar elementos pela classe porém no IE8 nao funciona o comando :

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('verdana14 toAdd');
```

tentei usar o :

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.verdana14.toAdd')
```

No chrome funciona porém no IE8 ainda n está funcionando.

Comment: Cade a classe verdana14 e toAdd no seu codigo html?

Answer (score 3):

Para compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos, deve-se criar uma rotina para isso.

A seguinte foi feita com base [nesta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808808/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-javascript):

```js
function findByClass(matchClass) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var resp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf(" "+matchClass+" ") > -1) {
            resp.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```js
var elementos = findByClass("crazy");
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    console.log(elementos[i].innerHTML);
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5VNM/)

Note que o "seletor" pode contar apenas o nome de **uma** classe. Para recuperar elementos que contenham exatamente 2 classes, por exemplo, poderíamos ajustar o método para receber dois nomes de classes ou executá-lo duas vezes e fazer uma intersecção dos resultados.

Vejamos outro exemplo com um seletor que aceita múltiplas classes:

```js
function findByClass(classes) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var matches = classes.split(' ');
    var resp = [];
    pula:
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matches.length; j++) {
            if((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf(" "+matches[j]+" ") < 0) {
                continue pula;
            }
        }
        resp.push(elems[i]);
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```js
var elementos = findByClass("crazy one");
for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
    console.log(elementos[i].innerHTML);
}
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNdLK/)

Comment: ~descaradamente copiada~. Eu ri. Quanto a resposta, essa solução aí é elegante para um navegado _não tão elegante_ assim

Comment: Concordo que o IE não seja elegante, apenas o Firefox é elegante, pois ele é uma raposa e raposas são elegantes, ainda mais raposas de fogo. - porém gostei da solução +1

Answer (score 3):

Use o seguinte no IE 8:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.destino');
```

Segundo a documentação no IE8 funciona apenas para seletores simples tal como este acima. Se você usar o seletor 'input.destino' por exemplo já deve dar problema.

Veja esse link http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t13

Outra alternativa é criar um Polyfill

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
  document.getElementsByClassName = function(search) {
    var doc = document, elements, pattern, i, results = [];
    if (doc.querySelectorAll) { // IE8
      return doc.querySelectorAll("." + search);
    }
    if (doc.evaluate) { // IE6, IE7
      pattern = ".//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' " + search + " ')]";
      elements = doc.evaluate(pattern, doc, null, 0, null);
      while ((i = elements.iterateNext())) {
        results.push(i);
      }
    } else {
      elements = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
      pattern = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + search + "(\\s|$)");
      for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if ( pattern.test(elements[i].className) ) {
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
}
```

Eu sempre prefiro criar um **Polyfill** pois posso colocar no meu HTML uma referencia ao arquivo JS que implementa a funcionalidade e todo o resto do meu código funciona da forma padrão e assim posso simplesmente ignorar o polyfill nos Browser modernos.